# SPFx - CSS for property pane

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-framework, spfx-custom-property-pane

I've created a SPFx web part called "Human Resources Announcements."
However, the name is too long for the property pane title to hold all of its value in one line.

[image]

How would I add custom CSS to the property pane?

I've tried adding to the .scss file for my web part

```
.propertyPane {
  .propertyPanePageTitle {
    font-size: $ms-font-size-m;
  }
}
```

but this doesn't do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similiar issue with the FabricUI:Dialog. The CSS will be overwritten or ignored. I ended up to use a "normal" css file and overwrite the css in the "traditional" way ;-)

1. Add a normal css file to your project (e.g. propertyPane.css under /components)
2. Add your CSS without the Class-Wrapper

   .propertyPanePageTitle {
   font-size: /* you have to use normal css */;
   }
3. include the CSS-file into your project (e.g. HumanResourcesAnnouncements.tsx)

   require("./propertyPane.css");